# Sort Events By Event Date, Not Post Date

Tags: wordpress, events

[Here's the page I'm working on.](https://www.graceuniversity.edu/events/)

This is what I was trying, but it won't validate.

```
$today = date('Ymd');
$args = array(
'post_type'         => 'events',
'posts_per_page'    => 10,
'meta_key'      => 'calendar_date', // name of custom field
'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
'order'             => 'ASC',
'meta_query' => array(
array(
'key'       => 'calendar_date',
'compare'   => '<=',
'value'     => $today,
)
),
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
$the_query->the_post();
```

Comment: What is your meta_key (calendar_date) date format?

Comment: Here is what I'm using on the home page, and it's working. [link](http://imgur.com/a/Hx8Uk)

Comment: But when I try to apply that to the EVENTS page it won't work. [link](http://imgur.com/a/6ogyk)

Comment: Do you use the same code in event page or modify something? because your both code are not same.

Comment: I didn't modify anything. What needs to be changed? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use this code in event page?

```
<?php
$today = date('m/d/Y');
$args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'events',
    'posts_per_page'    => 10,
    'orderby'       => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'             => 'ASC',
    'meta_key'      => 'calendar_date', // name of custom field
    'meta_compare'   => '<=',
    'meta_value'     => $today
);

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        $convert = strtotime( get_field('calendar_date') );
        $calendarDate = date('M d', $convert);
        ?>
        <div class="news-date">
            <p><?php echo $calendarDate; ?></p>
            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
            <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-right"></i>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: That is used in the single-events.php. I believe that is used to order the events on the left side column which is currently not working at all.

Comment: I edit my code. Please use this code and give me update.

Comment: Thank you for your work. I switched out the code, but it doesn't appear to be effecting it.